# Is there any downside in using ng-view on body tag?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm quite new to AngularJs so I'm reading a lot of documentation and tutorials.

Concerning ng-view, I've only seen it been used in a tag which will wrapper the view like:

```
<div ng-view>
  <-- here comes the view -->
</div>
```

But I was wondering, is there any downside in using it in the `body` tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not that I am aware of, Body tag is just another DOM element like DIV.

The only downside I am come up is that you can not have common elements like header/footer or sidebar shared by different views. And if you want to share some values between different views, you have to put it to the $rootScope, because there no other scope available between the $rootScope and the scope of your view

Comment: I'm new, but can't you put a controller on the html tag to contain scope?

Answer (score 1):

For me, putting the ng-view on body caused some side effects.

I am using jquery in my project. 
The idea is to include jquery before you include angular - and so `angular.element` will produce a jquery element.

Once I put ng-view on body, it seems I have to include jquery AFTER angular.

I have no idea why, but that made me switch back to ng-view on div.

I am not saying this is an angular bug or anything, just raising awareness of stuff that might happen if ng-view is on body.

Answer (score 1):

I also had issues when I used ng-view on  . I had a very simple app with a view that just loaded an image. The image said "Under construction". However when I used ng-view on body tag, the image was not visible many time on first load. I had to refresh the page 2-3 times before I could see the image. So I changed the position of ng-view to a div and this solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am also new, but it would make including scripts at the bottom of the body tag an issue to consider.

Answer (score 0):

For me, ng-view in body tag causes, every time the script files which is inside the body are reloading when routes happen.